# how to get a "desolate" sound?

Tags: theory

example: Detroit people mover Squarepusher

Comment: Not looking at the filming, that music could easily be anything but 'desolate'. The scenes help set - the scene.

Comment: I think 90% of the feeling is from the images. Imagine the same music against, let's say, a time lapse of a happy painting being painted...what would you feel then?

Comment: how could you describe this sound?

Comment: The synth - the one playing the chords - sounds like an early model playing the type of patch they used to call 'Brass' or 'Fat Brass', but which never sounded remotely like real brass instruments. What makes it sound vaguely desolate are those high notes bending downwards, like little glissandi. They sound a bit like sighs, and since we sigh when we're sad, they can be expressive, used in moderation. Here they're laid on with a trowel and they remind us we also sigh when we're bored.

Comment: What else makes it sound desolate? I guess the slowness and the absence of a pulse do a bit. But that synth is buzzy and hot. Something calm and cold might've worked better. The shots are quite arresting but for my money the music doesn't add anything much. But to each his own, as they say in France. In French.